# Is it a dumbing down of amor fati to use it to accept other people's behaviour and have less expectations of them?

Tags: nietzsche, self-help

Is it a dumbing down of amor fati to use it to accept other people's behaviour and have less expectations of them? It reminds me of [stoic tips](https://dailystoic.com/stoicism-modernity/) for a happier life, fabricated quotes by famous philosophers, but does it have any philosophical basis in Nietzsche's work? Specifically, I mean that *their* behaviour is *their* fate and inescapable for *them* (just as **your** pain is **your** pain and cannot be felt etc. by anyone else).

So either using it for 'acceptance' or turning it aorund to make it apply to others.

Comment: i would assume it is a dumbing down, yes :D

Comment: it's one thing to understand people are flawed, learn and have realistic expectations about them (which is to say, sometimes lower, sometimes higher than our uninformed hunches), and another to just accept this state of things and do nothing to change it. I think Nietszche would recommend the former and refuse the latter. See, in Genealogy of Morals, the chapter about the birds of prey and how he considers foolish to expect the powerful to not exert their power and be nice to the feeble.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, thanks, good comment @armand he is trying to change ppl

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand this concept, *amor fati* does not mean we should accept the world as it is. Rather, we should accept the cards that we were dealt, and start looking for ways to play them right -- to make this world a better place.

Comment: yeah well i agree we casn do some things about some things, but then it often seems that people will be the way they are whatever you yourself do, and it may help in some pseudo philosophical way to say *that's just their fate* rather than ascribe it to e.g. their character or their problems

Comment: The real change is never easy, that much is true.

Comment: it's so *lofty*, trying to shape the world into something better. ofc it's not a bad goal, but everyone gets sick and dies, often in tragic ways, and who does a anything except *help another person* (when they needed it). idk

Comment: @user66697 - Of course, every little bit counts. And some people do [achieve more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QoQ7TYWsioc). Ralph Waldo Emerson once said, "Once you make a decision, the universe conspires to make it happen." So dream big :)